# Logstash cannot find logstash.yml although it exists

Tags: logstash

Testing logstash as instructed [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/configuration.html).

This is the command I execute (it doesn't work without the --path.settings too):

```
/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -f logstash-simple.conf --path.settings /etc/logstash/logstash.yml
```

But I am getting this warning:

```
WARNING: Could not find logstash.yml which is typically located in $LS_HOME/config or /etc/logstash. You can specify the path using --path.settings.
```

Permissions should be ok for everyone to read logstash.yml:

```
ls -lsah /etc/
4.0K drwxrwxr-x   4 root root   4.0K Sep 15 16:35 logstash

ls -lsah /etc/logstash/
8.0K -rw-r--r--   1 root root 5.7K Sep 15 16:26 logstash.yml
```

Version:

```
/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash --version
logstash 5.6.0
```

Comment: You only need to set the directory with `--path.settings`, try `--path.settings /etc/logstash`. If this doesn't work, try to run it as user `logstash` (if you have created it, depends on which user logstash runs in your environment)

Comment: That works. Although I would still expect that logstash finds its config file in the default place if I leave out the parameter.

Comment: What happens if you run the service? This should be OK.